How can I apply GridSearchCV where my data are images organised into folders?
I have a custom CNN being implemented and am now trying to apply GridSearch for hyperparater tuning. I've included parts of my script that may be helpful. Any help would be appreciated. I consider myself a beginner in python and deep learning.

trainDirectory = "../Images/DATA3/Training"
testDirectory = "../Images/DATA3/Test"

trainingGenerator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
shear_range = 0.2,
zoom_range = 0.1,
horizontal_flip = True)
testingGenerator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

trainingSet = trainingGenerator.flow_from_directory(trainDirectory,
target_size = (101, 168),
batch_size = 16,
class_mode = 'binary')

testingSet = testingGenerator.flow_from_directory(testDirectory,
target_size = (101,168),
batch_size = 16,
class_mode = "binary",
)

imageSize = \[101,168,3\]
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters=16,kernel_size=(3,3),input_shape=imageSize,activation="relu",padding="same"))
model.add(MaxPool2D(strides=2,pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(64,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1,activation="sigmoid"))



To fine-tune hyperparameters using GridSearchCV, begin by installing the
scikeras library. Preprocess your data and define your model. Next, define a
dictionary containing hyperparameter names and their potential values. Wrap
your model within the KerasClassifier class. Finally, pass the wrapped model
and the hyperparameter dictionary to GridSearchCV and initiate the training
process with the fit method. I have implemented GridSearchCv , refer to the gist.
